# Inconsistent behaviour when using mix-blend-mode with overflow and

Tags: css, safari, webkit, overflow, mix-blend-mode

I'm experiencing a strange result in Safari where it seems the CSS attribute `mix-blend-mode` seems to stop  `overlow:hidden` of the parent (`.numWrap`) div from working. The example below is a snippet of the overall project, which is a flip-style timer app.

The use of `mix-blend-mode` is preferred as allows the shading to more naturally fall on the card below.

[Behaviour in Safari (all devices)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnLdw.png)

[Behaviour in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSysA.png)

See below some CSS/HTML I've isolated, exhibiting this behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    
    body {
        background-color: #aeccab;
    }

    .numWrap {
        font-size: 80pt;

        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        z-index: 25;

    }

    .numWrap-shadow {
        position: absolute;
        /*top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        /*background: linear-gradient(to right bottom,
                rgba(226, 219, 205, 0.753),
                rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1));*/
        /*left: 0;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        right: 0;*/
        border-radius: 2rem;
        border: 1px solid rgb(67, 29, 204);
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-shadow: inset 18px 18px 36px #a1a1a1c8;
        z-index: 19;

    }

    .time,
    .time-alt {
    color: rgba(76, 85, 71, 0.876);
    border: 1px dashed rgb(230, 0, 255); 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 300%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-property: transform;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    will-change: transform;
    background-color: #dedede;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="numWrap hoursWrap">
    <div class="numWrap-shadow"></div>

    <div class="time-alt time--hours inactive"><span>00</span></div>
    <div class="time time--hours"><span>00</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've worked through all parts of the relevant CSS to identify the issue. Disabling the `mix-blend-mode` within DevTools returns to the expected behaviour. This is not an issue in Chrome or Firefox (where most of my live testing has occured).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this issue, I have solved it. I think it has something to do with WebKit handling stacking contexts oddly (though I'm not clear on what that means).

To solve this, I moved `numWrap-shadow` out of the `numWrap` div and created a new container div for both, transferring the necessary attributes.

If anyone has further questions, happy to expand where I can!